# How to get image from user via Facebook Messenger in action.py in Rasa

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger, rasa, rasa-core

I’m working a Rasa project and currently on an action that can take image from user (via Facebook Messenger which I have already figured out how to integrate). I need to know how facebook.py (comes with rasa install) works and how can I get the image url that user sent from Facebook to tracker so that I can take the image from tracker abd process the image in action.py. Currently if I send an image the bot just gonna respond like this
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The image input format is defined here: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/main/rasa/core/channels/facebook.py#L118

Basically, the URL is taken and passed as the user input text to Rasa for processing. So you'll be able to access this like a normal text input.

In your custom action, access the input text from `tracker.latest_message.text`. This will have your image URL.